# Android SharedPreferences data not being saved (or I'm not retrieving it right)?

Tags: android

I'm trying to save two different numbers that the user enters into a SharedPreferences file (one is called Rider Number, the other is Pillion Number). When I tap on my Save Button, then back out of this screen and go back in, I'm getting the 2nd number in both the 1st and 2nd fields.

So I added a bunch of logging to see where it could be going wrong, and from what I can tell nothing is being saved to the SharedPreferences. The even weirder part is that when I load the app up after quitting it, the EditText boxes both show the 2nd value, so it must be saved somewhere.

**appSettings.xml:**

```
public class appSettings extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String tohPreferences = "Tour of Honor Preferences";
    public static final String riderNum = "000";
    public static final String pillionNum = "000";
    String riderNumToH = "000";
    String pillionNumToH = "000";

    String myEmailAddress = "me@example.com";
    String appVersionName;
    String jsonVersionName = "JSON 2019";
    private TextView versionDisplay;
    Button btnSendAppFeedback;
    EditText fieldRiderNumber;
    EditText fieldPillionNumber;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_settings);
        // my_child_toolbar is defined in the layout file
        Toolbar myChildToolbar =
                (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myChildToolbar);

        // Get a support ActionBar corresponding to this toolbar
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

        // Set the version number display
        getVersionName();

        // Enable the buttons
        btnSendAppFeedback = findViewById(R.id.btnSendAppFeedback);
        btnSendAppFeedback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchAppFeedbackIntent();
            }
        });

        Log.e("appSettings", "Initial Values: " + riderNumToH + " / " + pillionNumToH);
        fieldRiderNumber = findViewById(R.id.fieldRiderNumber);
        fieldPillionNumber = findViewById(R.id.fieldPillionNumber);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(tohPreferences,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(riderNum)) {
            Log.e("appSettings","riderNum set to " + riderNum);
            fieldRiderNumber.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(riderNum, ""));
        } else {
            Log.e("appSettings","riderNum Failed");
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(pillionNum)) {
            Log.e("appSettings","pillionNum set to " + pillionNum);
            fieldPillionNumber.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(pillionNum, ""));
        } else {
            Log.e("appSettings","pillionNum Failed");
        }

    }

    public void saveRiderInfo(View view) {
        riderNumToH = fieldRiderNumber.getText().toString();
        pillionNumToH = fieldPillionNumber.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(riderNum, riderNumToH);
        editor.putString(pillionNum, pillionNumToH);
        editor.commit();
        Log.e("appSettings","Screen Values " + riderNumToH + " / " + pillionNumToH);
        Log.e("appSettings","Retrieved Values: " + riderNum + " / " + pillionNum);
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.appSettingsView), R.string.resultsSettingsSaved,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

    private String getVersionName() {

        appVersionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
        versionDisplay = findViewById(R.id.lblAppVersionInfo);
        versionDisplay.setText("Version " + appVersionName + " | " + jsonVersionName);
        return appVersionName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Submits the bonus images via email.
     */
    private void dispatchAppFeedbackIntent() {
        Intent sendEmailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendEmailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        sendEmailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        sendEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{myEmailAddress});
        sendEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "TOH Feedback from Rider " + riderNumToH);
        sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "\n\nSent from TOH App\nAndroid Version " + appVersionName);
        this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmailIntent, "Sending email..."));
    }
}
```

**Logcat Output for the above code:**

```
E/appSettings: Initial Values: 000 / 000
E/appSettings: riderNum set to 000
E/appSettings: pillionNum set to 000
E/appSettings: Screen Values 123 / 987
E/appSettings: Retrieved Values: 000 / 000
E/appSettings: Initial Values: 000 / 000
E/appSettings: riderNum set to 000
E/appSettings: pillionNum set to 000
```

I've lost count of how many times Ive confirmed I didn't accidentally mix up my rider & pillion variables and I haven't found one. I'm sure I'm missing something basic (this is my first Android app), but I am lost as to what it is.

Comment: You're using the same key for both preferences; i.e.,`riderNum` and `pillionNum`  are both `"000"`. Those need to be different. Also, keys are usually meaningful strings, rather than numbers; e.g., `"rider_num"` and `"pillion_num"`. I would also mention that the convention for constants like those is to use all uppercase letters for the variable names; e.g., `public static final String RIDER_NUM = "rider_num";`.

Comment: @MikeM.Can you post as an answer so I can give you credit? That fixed it. Also, one extra question: How can I have the app default to these being set to "000" for each one? I use that value as a trigger to block some other actions and tell the user they haven't set the Rider number. I want to overwrite the 000 with whatever the user enters, but start with it set to 000 until they manually set it to something else.

Comment: If you mean the default value read from `SharedPreferences`, the second argument in the `getString()` method is for a default value, for which you could pass `"000"`. That is, `sharedpreferences.getString(riderNum, "000")`. Anyhoo, this is a common issue that has been asked here several times, so I would just mark this as a duplicate, rather than answer. We'll just call it a freebie. :-) If you'd like, you could just delete this. Otherwise, lemme know, and I'll find a duplicate for it. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer.

Comment: I'm trying to read that value in another activity and I'm getting a NullPointerException when I load the activity. I've tried both `String riderNumToH = sharedpreferences.getString("RiderNumber","000");` and `String riderNumToH = sharedpreferences.getString(appSettings.riderNum,"000");` (I included `import static net.tommyc.android.tourofhonor.appSettings.riderNum;` at the top of this activity)

Comment: It's unlikely that `getString()` is throwing an NPE internally. What's the Exception message?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{net.tommyc.android.tourofhonor/net.tommyc.android.tourofhonor.captureBonus}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: `sharedpreferences` is null. Did you forget to assign it before trying to call `getString()` on it in that second `Activity`? That is, `sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(tohPreferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`.

Comment: I have that declaration in the onCreate method for that activity (captureBonus is the other activity). When I tried to declare it above the methods, I get a ton of errors on the line.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, but it should be set up exactly like you have it in the posted `Activity` here – the `SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;` declaration at the top of the class, then the `sharedpreferences = ...` assignment in `onCreate()`, and any `getString()` calls after that, or in other methods.

Comment: Ah, I see where I went wrong. I was trying to declare and set it at the top, instead of declaring it and then setting it later via the method. Thank you!